# Flash recorder not including cookies in Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, cookies, rtmp

Greetings.

I have a problem where a flash player, when run through firefox, is not including the HTTP cookies. These are included when run through internet explorer.

I want to know if anyone knows how to force flash to include cookies when communicating with a flash server?

#### Background Information

We have a flash recorder  which connects to a red5 server. These connections are opened through a load balancer which offers a pool address. There are multiple servers in the pool.

The recorder sends data using the RTMPT protocol. This sends the RMTP over HTTP (this allows firewall traversal). To ensure data arrives at the correct server we used cookie based load balancing. If a certain cookie is present the load balancer directs the connection to the correct server.

This cookie is set when the user logs into the site through thier web browser. The flash player then includes these cookies in the RTMTP HTTP requests when communicating with the server. This ensures the RMTPT connection is opened to the correct server.

Using fiddler, I grabbed some of the traffic (from IE) to show what I mean:

`POST http://hostname/idle/31283773/0 HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/x-fcs

User-Agent: Shockwave Flash

Host: host

Content-Length: 1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Pragma: no-cache

Cookie: JSESSIONID=sessionid; target-server=target-server-value`

Unfortunately, when using firefox, the cookies are not included in the traffic to the server:

`POST http://hostname/idle/31283773/0 HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/x-fcs

User-Agent: Shockwave Flash

Host: host

Content-Length: 2030

Connection: Keep-Alive

Pragma: no-cache`

The player is written in action script and initialized through javascript/HTML. We use NetConnection / NetStream to speak to the server.

I have access to the target server ID in the HTML / javascript which loads the flash recorder but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to include the cookies when sending the RTMPT data, or even is such a thing is possible.

#### What I'd like to know

Can anyone tell me:
1 - Is it possible to instruct the flash recorder to include certain cookies when speaking with the flash server? They're automatically included when running through IE.
2 - If so - can anyone tell me how?

I've spent a few hours googling for solutions with no luck so far - hopefully someone here may have an idea :-)
Thanks for your time, and if you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Hi Gary, Can you tell me how were you capturing the cookies at the Server.! Right now I am not able to collect the cookies at the server. :(

Comment: Hi Gary, six years passed, sorry to bother you, but I met the same problem today, I am wondering that if you remember how to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at why the cookies arent being sent? Is this not becuase you are using load balancing and the domain is changing? Firefox only allows the same domain to access the same cookies.

Just an idea, hope it helps.

Pete